# Not Able to initalize bundlr for etherum

Tags: solidity, ethereum-classic

```
const privateKey = user_wallet.private_key;
const bundlr = new Bundlr(arweaveUrl, "Ethereum", privateKey );
await bundlr.ready();
```

Im not able to initalize Bundlr for etherum.

Giving me the following error

```
{
    "message": "Invalid typed array length: 0xPRIVATEKEY"
}
```

Comment: can you post a private key example. it seems that the used format is incorrect

Comment: I used it as it is just from the DB ,its not at all encrypted